# Symfony JsonResponse converts snake_case attributes to CamelCase

Tags: php, symfony, jsonresponse

I am new to symfony, and trying to build a json API.
I am trying to return a Doctrine generated Entity called `User` as a response to one of the endpoints. However, when passing an instance to the json function :

```
class UserController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/users/id')]
    public function getUser(Request $request, UsersRepository $usersRepository, SessionInterface $session): JsonResponse
    {
      $user = $usersRepository->getUserById(1);

      return $this->json($user, $status = 200, $headers = [], $context = []);
    }
}
```

I get in response the right User json object, but all parameters have been converted from snake_case to camelCase.

I am expecting this:

```
{"user_id":1,"email":"admin@devsecurely.com","reset_token":null,"reset_token_expires":null,"active":null}
```

But I am getting this:

```
{"userId":1,"email":"admin@devsecurely.com","resetToken":null,"resetTokenExpires":null,"active":null}
```

The parameters in the Entity class have a snake_case naming format, as do the column names in the database.

Why is `JsonResponse` behaving like this? Is there a way to fix this?

Thank you in advance for your help.

EDIT: below is the code for the Users Entity:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UsersRepository;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: UsersRepository::class)]
class Users
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $user_id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 500)]
    private ?string $email = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 500, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $reset_token = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATETIME_MUTABLE)]
    private ?\DateTimeInterface $reset_token_expires = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?bool $active = null;

    public function getUserId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->user_id;
    }

    public function setUserId(int $user_id): self
    {
        $this->user_id = $user_id;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getResetToken(): ?string
    {
        return $this->reset_token;
    }

    public function setResetToken(?string $reset_token): self
    {
        $this->reset_token = $reset_token;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getResetTokenExpires(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->reset_token_expires;
    }

    public function setResetTokenExpires(\DateTimeInterface $reset_token_expires): self
    {
        $this->reset_token_expires = $reset_token_expires;

        return $this;
    }

    public function isActive(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->active;
    }

    public function setActive(bool $active): self
    {
        $this->active = $active;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share your Entity class code here. I am sure that field's variable name is in camelCase.

Comment: @BhavinNakrani I edited my question and added the Entity class source code. You can see that all fields are in snake_case

Answer (score 1):

You are experiencing a weird behavior since the convention is to have CamelCase attributes in Objects and Entities. Usually people ask the opposite: converting CamelCase to snake_case and that can be done using the `CamelCaseToSnakeCaseNameConverter`.

In your case, you can force the serialized name using this annotation on your Entity:

```
class User
{
    #[SerializedName('reset_token')]
    private $reset_token;
    //...
```

To avoid annotating your entity you can also use a yaml configuration (see https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html) or a DTO.

Comment: I tried adding the annotation, but it gets ignored, and the behavior stayed the same. I added the annotation definition `use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\SerializedName;`

Answer (score 0):

Please use `name` in annotation

```
#[ORM\Column(name:'email', length: 500)]
private ?string $email = null;

#[ORM\Column(name:'reset_token', length: 500, nullable: true)]
private ?string $reset_token = null;

#[ORM\Column(name:'reset_token_expires', type: Types::DATETIME_MUTABLE)]
private ?\DateTimeInterface $reset_token_expires = null;
```